# Hyundai Getz 2010 making creaking sound

Tags: brakes, hyundai, noise

Car: Hyundai Getz 2010 (3 door)
Kilometers: 19,000 (11,500 miles)

Bought my first car a few weeks ago, got it checked out by a mechanic and all was good. He mentioned there was very minor impact damage on front cross member bolt and washer, passenger side rear.

Now though, when driving at low speeds, turning & braking, the car makes a creaking noise. It comes from the rear of the car... 
I have a pretty limited knowledge of cars, but is this a serious issue?  It's definitely an annoying one, but does it warrant immediate action (aka going to a mechanic asap) 
Is it related to the previously mentioned impact damage?

Comment: I doubt it's a serious issue, one that requires immediate attention. Considering the low mileage on the vehicle, I'd assume the squeak is related to the impact damage. Yes, I'd get it to a mechanic or body shop to see if there is something more going on than meets the eye.